# Exclude elements from query

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, is it possible the following action?

Suppose I have a collection like this, with an index on the name field:

```
{
 name: A
 rand: 123
 array: [a1,a2..]
},
.
.
{
 name: Z
 rand: 567
 array: [z1,z2..]
}
```

In my query I want to extract at random some documents (based on that rand field), but to exclude other documents, so they should not be choosen.

For example:  Extract a document at random, but exclude the doc where the name is A or B

Comment: Depending on how you are using rand field but if it's a query just add {"name":{$nin:["A","B"]}, rand:<whatever>} to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.yourcollection.find({rand: 123, name: { $not: { $in: [ 'A', 'B' ] }}})
```